# Problems calculating area of polygons using dissolve function in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Im trying to calculate the area of terrestrial protected areas in Google Earth Engine using the polygons from the world database on protected areas. I'm iterating over a list of countries and for each country only selecting terrestrial polygons and dissolving them so that it dosen't count polygons inside other polygons yet my results differ quite a bit from the numbers I get from protectedplanet.com, which uses the same data set and I'm not quite sure why.

Here's my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6dc92998c40df81e15d954471c70f3d4

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons');

var protected_terrestrial = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.eq('MARINE', '0'),
  ee.Filter.lt('STATUS_YR', 2016), 
  ee.Filter.neq('STATUS', 'proposed')));

var countries = ee.List(['NIC', 'CRI', 'PAN', 'COL', 'VEN', 'SUR', 'ECU', 'PER', 'BRA', 'BOL', 'PRY', 'URY', 'ARG', 'SLE', 'LBR', 'CIV', 'GHA', 'TGO', 'BEN', 'NGA', 'CMR', 'GNQ', 'GAB', 'COD', 'COG', 'RWA', 'UGA', 'KEN', 'TZA', 'MOZ', 'MWI', 'AGO', 'ZWE', 'ZMB', 'BWA', 'ZAF', 'MDG', 'THA', 'IND', 'MMR', 'LAO', 'VNM', 'KHM', 'MYS', 'IDN', 'PHL', 'PNG', 'TLS']);
```

// Create a list to store the results

```
var results = [];
```

// Loop over the countries and calculate the protected area for each country
co

```
untries.evaluate(function(countries) {
  countries.forEach(function(country) {
    var selected = protected_terrestrial.filter(ee.Filter.and(
      ee.Filter.eq('PARENT_ISO', country),
      ee.Filter.neq('STATUS', 'proposed')));
```

//Dissolve polygons inside each other so that it creates one polygon for the entire country

```
var all = ee.FeatureCollection(selected).geometry().dissolve();

var polygonArea = all.area({'maxError': 1});
var polygonareakm = ee.Number(polygonArea).divide(ee.Number(1000000));
```

// Add the results to the list

```
results.push([country, polygonareakm]);
```

});

// Export the results as a CSV file to Google Drive

```
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(results.map(function(row) {
      return ee.Feature(null, {country: row[0], protected_area: row[1]});
    })),
    description: 'protected_areas_by_country',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take collection.geometry(), overlapping polygons are merged in ways that can be counter-intuitive, and therefore it's an operation you should essentially never use on a collection.

Instead, flatten the collection to an image using paint or reduceToImage and compute the area using pixels.  (`geometry` could come from country here)

```
var area = ee.Image(0).paint(collection, 1)
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry, 100)
```